# QGIS - Clip size too large

Tags: qgis

I clipped a small scene out of a larger orthophoto and the output file is 3 times as big (7.5 GB) as the original tiff-file (2.5 GB). How to get it small while keeping the original resolutuion?

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply a compression to the image being created. Using 'Processing  > Toolbox  > Clip Raster By Extent', under Advanced parameters you can set the compression type. I believe a good one to use is 'Deflate' and that'll reduce the created file size.[image]

Comment: Thanks. Where do I find this function??

Comment: You can find it in the Processing toolbox. [Screenshot to clarify](http://imgur.com/a/yv8i5)

Comment: Thanks! The outcome looks a bit strange (from the colours) and has a black box around. Tried it with another pc and another qgis version with the first tool and here the output tiff is "only" 3.5GB. I will just use this as it seems it is not possible to propper extract a clip with qgis in probriate time..